# Is something considered stolen if it possibly could have been lost?

Tags: canada, theft, passport

I had lived in a rental house where the landlord had the notion he could "immediately evict someone" if he felt like it. I installed a security camera. I have a video of the landlord and a couple other people entering my suite and snooping around. While I did I not see them take anything, the camera was limited by its viewing angel and I couldn't always see their hands. I moved homes and months latter I notice my passport was missing. The video shows the landlord going into the closet I had stored it in, but doesn't show him take anything out (though he could've put it in his pocket while still in the closet).

I've reported this to the passport office and police. They didn't really care, saying I could have just lost it. This is possible. There's other circumstantial evidence like how he falsely accused me of stealing his passport.

Can this be brought to small claims court? Should the police or some other government agency care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is something considered stolen if it possibly could have been lost?

Something is considered stolen if it was stolen.

You don't have your passport + Someone entered the room where it was ≠ They stole it

> Can this be brought to small claims court?

What damage did you suffer that could be remedied by a monetary settlement? Sure, the landlord entering your room without your permission is probably unlawful but it's not clear that it did you any damage. No damage; no case.

> Should the police or some other government agency care?

Here is a ranking of government cares:

1. Getting reelected
2. National security
3. Economic Management

...

42,567. Murder

...

421,762. Passport Fraud

...

7,656,232. Passport theft

...

58,432,546.  Passports that might have been stolen but probably weren't